# In a MLE what are the rules for getting things out of the product symbol $\prod$ in our $f(x_1,...,x_n | \theta )$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, probability-distributions

In a MLE what are the rules for getting things out of the product symbol in our $f(x_1,...,x_n | \theta )$?

What I mean is once we have the density function of our distribution we write $f(x_1,...,x_n | \theta ) = \prod_{i=1}^n$ (We have the distribution formula here).

I want to know what are the rules for getting things out i.e does
$\prod_{i=1}^n 2x_i\theta = 2\theta n \prod_{i=1}^n x_i$ ?

This is a very simple example. What happens when you have an exponent?
does $\prod_{i=1}^n 2^{x_i}\theta = 2^{\sum x_i}\theta $ ?

What happens when the exponent does not contain the random variable X how do we get it out? i.e does $\prod_{i=1}^n 2^{\theta + x_i} = 2^{\theta n + \sum x_i}$ ?

*It all boils down to when do I know when to multiply by $n$ or not when getting the expressions out of the product symbol?* This is what I want answered.

Comment: Just take $n=2,3$ and see what you get. Then for general $n$ it should be obvious. This has nothing to do with MLE or distributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, write it out.

\begin{align}
\prod_{i=1}^n 2x_i\theta &= (2x_1 \theta)(2x_2 \theta)(2x_3 \theta) \cdots (2x_n \theta) \\
&= (2\theta)x_1 (2\theta)x_2(2\theta)x_3 \cdots (2\theta) x_n \\
&= (2\theta)^n x_1 x_2 x_3 \cdots x_n = (2\theta)^n \prod_{i = 1}^n x_i.
\end{align}

> It all boils down to when do I know when to multiply by n or not when getting the expressions out of the product symbol?

You multiply by $n$ when you are pulling a constant out of each summand:

$$ \sum_{i = 1}^n (f(i) + c) = f(1) + c + f(2) + c + \dots + f(n) + c = nc + \sum_{i = 1}^n f(i). $$

The corresponding rule for products is

$$ \prod_{i = 1}^n f(i) \cdot c = c^n \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n f(i). $$

Another rule that is sometimes helpful is

$$ \prod_{i = 1}^n c^{f(i)} = c^{f(1)} c^{f(2)} \cdots c^{f(n)} = c^{f(1) + f(2) + \dots + f(n)} = c^{\sum_{i = 1}^n f(i)}$$

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: $\prod_{i=1}^n 2^{\theta + x_i} = 2^{\theta n + \sum x_i}$ was it correct it seems to involve both what you would do for products with what you would for sums?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right @Nassims